# How to plot this parametric curve

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to plot this parametric function:

`(cos(t)+(t)*sin(t), sin(t)+(t)*cos(t)) (0≤t≤π)`

which gives the curve below:

[image]

This is my attempt, but for some reason it doesn't work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick] plot[variable=\t,domain=0:180,smooth,thick] ({cos(\t)-(\t)*sin(\t)},{sin(\t)-(\t)*cos(\t)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How should I fix these codes?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: `(\t r)` has no meaning as far as I know(I could be wrong). Do you want minus or plus in your formula?

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I added the preamble part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand hpekristiansen's comment:

1. You don't need `(\t r)` outside the `sin` or `cos` functions. You already defined `\t` in radians because the `domain` is `0:pi`. However, you need that inside the trigonometric functions, that as default take values in degrees.
2. You say you want to draw the function

```
(cos(t)+(t)*sin(t), sin(t)+(t)*cos(t))
```

but in your code is

```
(cos(t)-(t)*sin(t), sin(t)-(t)*cos(t))
```

However, I get an approximate result with

```
(cos(t)+(t)*sin(t), sin(t)-(t)*cos(t))
```

The complete code could be:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,scale=2]
\draw[help lines] (-1.25,0) grid [step=0.5] (1.75,3.75);
\draw[-latex] (-1.25,0) -- (1.75,0) node [right] {$x$};
\draw[-latex] (0,0)     -- (0,3.75) node [above] {$y$};
\foreach[count=\j]\i in {-1,-0.5,0.5,1,1.5}
  \draw (\i,0.05) -- (\i,-0.05) node [below] {$\i\ifnum\j<3\phantom{-}\fi$};
\foreach\i in {0.5,1,...,3.5}
  \draw (0.05,\i) -- (-0.05,\i) node [left]  {$\i$};
\draw[red, thick] plot[variable=\t,domain=0:pi,smooth,thick] ({cos(\t r)+\t*sin(\t r)},{sin(\t r)-\t*cos(\t r)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the output
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the code & output.
I think I'll try again :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.75]
  \tkzInit[xmin=-5,xmax=2,ymin=-7,ymax=3.5,xstep=.5,ystep=.5] \tkzGrid
  \tkzAxeXY
  \tkzFctPar[samples=400,domain=0:pi,red,smooth,thick]{cos(t)+(t)*sin(t)}{sin(t)-(t)*cos(t)}
  \tkzFctPar[samples=400,domain=pi:2*pi,blue,smooth,thick]{cos(t)+(t)*sin(t)}{sin(t)-(t)*cos(t)}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank-you for the code with 'tkz-fct'. Honestly, I didn't know about it until your answer:) I think I'll look through its manual to understand those commands.

Comment: @ta-ka  It is an interface between the user and `TikZ'. `TikZ' allows you to work with `Gnuplot'. You need to know some of the options of `TikZ` to use it well.